# Vue + Typescript - losing intellisense when defining component using typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js, intellisense

When I define component using Typescript I lose intellisense for props when using this component.

My component:

```vue
<!-- components/MyGreeting.vue -->
<template>
  <div>Hello {{ name }}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

Usage:

```vue
<!-- pages/about.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <MyGreeting />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyGreeting from '../components/MyGreeting.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    MyGreeting,
  },
}
</script>
```

When I put my cursor here <MyGreeting */> and press option+esc (on mac) I get no information about available props.

BUT when I define this component without Typescript:

```
<!-- components/MyGreeting.vue -->
<template>
  <div>Hello {{ name }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

It behaves like it should - in parent component after option+esc the first three options are :name, name and v-bind:name.

I initialised project using Nuxt (2.15.8), with Eslint, Prettier and TS. (I'll be happy to provide more info if needed).

Any ideas how to get intellisense back?

Comment: Which intellisense? It's IDE that provides it, not a framework

Comment: I mean VS Code’s intellisense (I use Volar extension for Vue). As I described, when I setup a Vue file WITHOUT typescript (no lang=“ts”, no Vue.extend,…) I get what I want - VS Code shows me component´s props in the dropdown. When I use TS, props are not in the dropdown :/

Comment: it's not even the IDE itself but the plugins. Guess your vue plugin can't do typescript (yet?). The typescript plugin for example relies a lot on the typescript language to provide information and I guess neither of those are aware of .vue files and how to understand them because they aren't legal .ts files.

Comment: Ok, I think I found an answer to my problem (I should have read Volar documentation more carefully). 
The answer was instead of defining Vue component like this: export default Vue.extend({ ... }) to define it like this: export default defineComponent({ ... }). Now the "Cross-component props type-checking" works as expected.